# Select ... CASE WHEN ... ORDER BY alias

Tags: mysql, case

Here are my tables:

Table PROGRAMME prg

- prg_id
- ln1_id
- pmt_id
- prg_commission
- dep_id

Table COMMISSION com

- com_id
- pmt_id
- ln1_id
- dep_id
- com_commission

Table PROMOTEUR pmt

- pmt_id
- pmt_txcommission

I need to get the "commission" of the table programme

But when it's null or empty (prg.commission), i need to get the "commission" value from the table "Commission" (com.commission - by the ln1_id, pmt_id and dep_id matching from both table).

If there is no result matching (no result in table COMMISSION where com.ln1_id = prg.ln1_id AND com.pmt_id = prg.ln1_id and com.dep_id = prg.dep_id) i need to get the "Commission" of PROMOTEUR (pmt.commission)

I don't really have idea how to do it in Sql... it would be easier in PHP condition but i have to do it on MySQL because after getting the good value of "Commission" for each of my programmes, i need to ORDER them by ASC...

I'm not sure if i'm easily understandable (english not my native language). Here is an exemple of what i tried (not successfully sadly) because there is a bit too much condition for me !

```
SELECT prg.commision AS commission, pmt.commission AS commission, com.commission AS commission
FROM (((PROGRAMME prg
LEFT JOIN LOINIVEAU1 ln1 ON ln1.ln1_id = prg.ln1_id)
LEFT JOIN PROMOTEUR pmt ON pmt.pmt_id = prg.pmt_id)
LEFT JOIN COMMISSION com ON com.pmt_id = pmt.pmt_id)
WHERE 
    CASE prg.comission != null 
      THEN prg.comission 
      ELSE CASE com.commission != null 
             THEN com.commission 
             ELSE pmt.commission 
      THEN pmt.commission 
ORDER BY commission ASC
```

Comment: Each `CASE` needs its closing `END`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry if only you had a nickel for everytime you have said that...

Comment: I dont get what the last THEN is for in your CASE and you need to have an END to each case

Comment: @JohnRuddell If I had to return a dime every time someone completed step 1 but not step 2, I'd still be broke. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry :( sigh... i've noticed a pattern.. theres about 15 unique questions on here and the rest are some form of duplicate that nobody takes the time to research for. that and then the questions are not asked properly

Comment: @Strawberry This question is fine.. OP has clearly given their data_structure and described the query they want in detail. They've even had a go at the query themselves. Fiddles are nice, but not always necessary.. why not have a go at understanding and answering before copy-pasting some blurb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
   SELECT COALESCE(prg.commission, com.commission, pmt.commission) resolved_commission
     FROM PROGRAMME prg
LEFT JOIN COMMISSION com 
       ON com.pmt_id = prg.pmt_id
      AND com.ln1_id = prg.ln1_id
      AND com.dep_id = prg.dep_id
LEFT JOIN PROMOTEUR pmt 
       ON pmt.pmt_id = prg.pmt_id
 ORDER BY resolved_commission
```

I have taken the following steps:

- Removed the `LEFT JOIN` to `LOINIVEAU1` as this does not appear to be necessary
- Updated the other `LEFT JOIN` conditions to reflect those in your description
- Used `COALESCE` to return the first not null value from the comma-separated columns.. this replaces the `CASE` statement that you have incorrectly placed in the `WHERE` clause.
- Removed the unnecessary parentheses.

As another pointer.. never use `!= NULL` use `IS NOT NULL` instead.. as it turns out I did not need this in my solution.

**UPDATE**

Following further information:

```
   SELECT CASE 
            WHEN prg.commission > 0
               AND prg.commissionstart >= CURDATE()
               AND prg.commissionend < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
              THEN prg.commission
            WHEN com.commission > 0
              THEN com.commission
            WHEN pmt.commission > 0
              THEN pmt.commission
            ELSE 0 /* Whatever you want, probably 0 */
          END resolved_commission
     FROM PROGRAMME prg
     JOIN PROGRAMME_DEPARTMENT prg_dep
       ON prg_dep.prg_id = prg.id /* Guessing the JOIN here */
LEFT JOIN COMMISSION com 
       ON com.pmt_id = prg.pmt_id
      AND com.ln1_id = prg.ln1_id
      AND com.dep_id = prg_dep.dep_id
LEFT JOIN PROMOTEUR pmt 
       ON pmt.pmt_id = prg.pmt_id
      AND pmt.commissionstart >= CURDATE()
      AND pmt.commissionend < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 ORDER BY resolved_commission
```

Should get you a little closer..

You could replace `x > 0` with `x IS NOT NULL and x > 0` in the `CASE` for added clarity.

I would also seriously consider placing all the commissions in the `COMMISSION` table with a start and end and replacing `prg.commission*` and `pmt.commission*` with a link through an intermediate to this table.. this way you can rid yourself of all the `0` values and use a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` to get the resolved_commission.

**PERFORMANCE TWEAKS**

Use `EXPLAIN [EXTENDED] ...` to see how your query is being executed and play around with composite indexing combinations of the following columns on each table:

- `PROGRAMME`: ([id,], pmt_id, ln1_id, commission, commissionstart, commissionend)
- `PROGRAMME_DEPARTMENT`: (pmt_id, ln1_id, dep_id)
- `COMMISSION`: (pmt_id, ln1_id, dep_id, commission)
- `PROMOTEUR`: (pmt_id, commission, commissionstart, commissionend)

Comment: Yeah it seems it could work like that but actually it's not... In my structure i have an "intermediate table" between Prg and Dep (prg.vil_id = vil.vil_id / vil.dep_id = dep.dep_id -- But i'm barely sure it's not the problem, i adapted your proposition). I guess the problem  with COALESCE is that my values of "commission" (prg, com and pmt) are 0 and not null :S (it was a mistake from me) so it always return me the "prg_commission".
Another question: What's the result if all values are "0" ? (Returning null ?)

Comment: Oh and yeah... i have 2 extras parameters.... 
there is 2 date for thoses "commissions". A start and a End so i have to take the "prg_commission" only if prg.commissionstart >= today && prg.commissionend <= today (same goes for pmt with pmt.commissionstart and pmt.commissionend) so i don't know if can put them on the "WHERE" condition...

Comment: Yeah ! Amazing it works ! 
(PS: INTERVAL 1 **DAY** / No "S" :))
Thanks you very much !!

Comment: It works perfectly but... with my 15xx programmes and around 150 promoteur... the query takes arround 20sec.... i don't know if there is a way to make it faster... i know there is a lot of thing to check but still :S

Comment: @Dabeliuteef I have updated with a brief performance hint at the bottom. You should be able to get this query singing with the right indexes.

Comment: WOW, from 20sec to 0.01 with Index, that's REALLY impressive, thanks you !!